# Intersect on ArrayList with objects groovy

Tags: groovy

I have two array lists with objects of a domain class 'User'

```
a = [User : 35, User : 36, User : 37]
b = [User : 32, User : 33, User : 34, User : 35, User : 36, User : 37]
```

When I perform *intersect* (*java.util*), it returns an empty list. How can I find the common objects in array list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the fact that You keep maps (with same key) on the list.

Try:

```
def a = [User1 : 35, User2 : 36, User3 : 37]
def b = [User4 : 32, User5 : 33, User6 : 34, User1 : 35, User2 : 36, User3 : 37]

assert a.intersect(b) == [User1:35, User2:36, User3:37]
```

When You modify it to contain IDs only it behaves as expected:

```
def a = [35, 36, 37]
def b = [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37]

assert a.intersect(b) == [35,36,37]
```

See it?